# Getting error SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists, but it works on RazorSQL

Tags: php, sql, subquery

I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'product_name'
```

when I try to compute the average of a column from a subquery. 
Earlier, I tried creating a view to represent the subquery but I kept getting errors that the view didn't exist. The code works fine in RazorSQL just not for my web app.

```
$sql_energy = "SELECT AVG(energy_100g) AS energy
        FROM (SELECT *
                FROM Info_unempty
                INNER JOIN
                Favorites ON Info_unempty.id = Favorites.favorite
                LIMIT 5000) AS subq";
```

Please help! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sounds like `product_name` exists in both `Info_unempty` and `Favorites` table. Just select out the energy_100g column in your subquery `SELECT AVG(energy_100g) AS energy FROM (SELECT energy_100g FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks! gonna figure out how to give you rep. Ok not enough rep to even upvote comments gg

Comment: What database are you using? Sometimes different databases have ever-so-subtle differences in the syntax. What works in RazorSQL is not guaranteed to work in MySQL, Postgres, Sybase, Oracle, or anything else.

Comment: Should be sqlite but tbh I don't know because I got errors for sqlite syntax. I've just been going about it haphazardly

Comment: @JasonTu if that answered your question I can just put it as an answer and you can mark it as the answer. As UncaAlby said, some databases treat the data differently and can completely ignore the fact it's duplicated

Comment: Sorry just saw this yea you can do that.